# Installing openssl on RHEL 6.2

Tags: linux, yum, openssl, redhat-enterprise-linux

Trying to install openssl-devel on RHEL 6.2.

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

And i am getting this error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686 (rhel62)
       Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.47.el6
       Removing: glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201111171049.x86_64/6.2)
           glibc-common = 2.12-1.47.el6
       Updated By: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.x86_64 (rhel62-update)
           glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.7
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

--skip-broken does not help.
How can I fix this?

---

Update:
Fixed by updating ro RHEL 6.4

Comment: Are you mixing 32bit and 64bit? What error do you get if you try to uninstall `glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64` manually?

Comment: We don't have enough of your output of yum. **What** package does it say is going to be installed. The `.x86_64` or the `i686` version ? I think there is some mixing of 32bit and 64bit going on here. Please give the **complete** output of `yum install openssl-devel`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making sure you have up to date information in your RPM databases? Something along the lines `yum clean all && yum update` might be in order at this point.

Comment: Got the same error on `yum update`